# Qt 5.3 connect with lambda

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, events, lambda

I'm using Qt 5.3 with MinGW 4.8.2 (due to client restrictions the Qt version cannot be upgraded).
Trying to `connect` a QTcpSocket with a lambda expression ends up in a compiler error.

I have imported `<QTcpSocket>` and my class inherits `QObject` publicly. The `Q_OBJECT` macro has also been added to the header file.

This is how I am trying to connect the socket to a lambda function:

```
void TCPRequests::handleClient() {
    QTcpSocket* sock = serv -> nextPendingConnection();
    connect(sock, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [sock]()
    {
        // Do nothing
    });
}
```

This compiles and works correctly on Qt 5.8 but not on 5.3 with MinGW 4.8.2.

I have also tried to do
`connect(sock, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, [sock]() {...});` (note I am also passing `this` as the third argument), but it makes no difference.

The resulting errors are:

First:

> D:\Documents\Development\X\TCPRequests.cpp:43: error: no matching function for call to 'TCPRequests::connect(QTcpSocket*&, void (QIODevice::*)(), TCPRequests::handleClient()::__lambda0)'
>        });

Second:

> D:\Documents\Development\X\TCPRequests.cpp:43: error: template argument for 'template static typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<((int)(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer::ArgumentCount) >= 0), QMetaObject::Connection>::Type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer::Object*, Func1, Func2)' uses local type 'TCPRequests::handleClient()::__lambda0'
>        });

Third:

> D:\Documents\Development\X\TCPRequests.cpp:43: error: template argument for 'template static typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer::ArgumentCount == (-1)), QMetaObject::Connection>::Type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer::Object*, Func1, Func2)' uses local type 'TCPRequests::handleClient()::__lambda0'
>        });

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to add `CONFIG += c++11` to your project file (`.pro` file) to enable c++11 features in your project.

The reason why not giving a error in Qt 5.8 is because starting in Qt 5.7.0 the c++11 is enabled by default and old compilers that doesn't supports c++11 are not supported. See the [note](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.7):

> **C++11 Support Required from the compiler**
>
> Qt has enabled usage of C++11 in Qt applications for a long time, but
>   with Qt 5.7 we are also enabling use of C++11 in the Qt modules.
>   Therefore Qt 5.7 requires C++11 support from the compiler, and has
>   removed support from older compilers not providing adequate C++11
>   support.

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be nice that Qt Creator warned you in these cases